# Can't set breakpoint on throwing exception (__cxa_throw) in gdb 12.1

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Windows 10. Binary compiled with C++ 12.2.0 under Mingw64.

I can't set breakpoint on throwing exception (__cxa_throw) in Clion bundled gdb 12.1.
The same problem with Mingw64 GDB 12.1 and Mingw64 GDB 11.1.

But all work with Mingw64 GDB 10.1.

On starting gdb:

```
GNU gdb (GDB; JetBrains IDE bundle; build 152) 12.1

Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.

There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.

This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".

Type "show configuration" for configuration details.

For bug reporting instructions, please see:

<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:

    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".

Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".

Function "swift_willThrow" not defined.

Function "_CxxThrowException" not defined.

Function "swift_errorRetain" not defined.

unset env HOME
```

I see suspicious "not defined".

But the real problem in the following.

In non working bundled gdb 12.1:

```
(gdb) info symbol __cxa_throw

__cxa_throw in section .text of C:\Users\Veter\Desktop\Dev\_src\robo_003\cmake-build-debug\robo_001.exe

(gdb) info functions __cxa_throw

All functions matching regular expression "__cxa_throw":

Non-debugging symbols:

0x00007ff76b112108 __cxa_throw

0x00007ffe67a75f68 __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length

0x00007ffe67a75f70 __cxa_throw

(gdb) info symbol 0x00007ff76b112108

__cxa_throw in section .text of C:\Users\Veter\Desktop\Dev\_src\robo_003\cmake-build-debug\robo_001.exe

(gdb) info symbol 0x00007ffe67a75f70

__cxa_throw in section .text of C:\Users\Veter\Desktop\Dev\robo\Qt5Core.dll

(gdb) break __cxa_throw

Function "__cxa_throw" not defined.

Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

Breakpoint is not set.

In working external Mingw64 gdb 10.1. Same exe and libraries:

```
(gdb) info symbol __cxa_throw

__cxa_throw in section .text of C:\Users\Veter\Desktop\Dev\_src\robo_003\cmake-build-debug\robo_001.exe

(gdb) info functions __cxa_throw

All functions matching regular expression "__cxa_throw":

Non-debugging symbols:

0x00007ffe670e5f68 __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length

0x00007ffe670e5f70 __cxa_throw

(gdb) info symbol 0x00007ffe670e5f70

__cxa_throw in section .text of C:\Users\Veter\Desktop\Dev\robo\Qt5Core.dll

(gdb) break __cxa_throw

Note: breakpoint 2 also set at pc 0x7ffe670e5f70.

Note: breakpoint 2 also set at pc 0x7ff76b112108.

Breakpoint 7 at 0x7ff76b112108 (2 locations)

(gdb) info symbol 0x7ff76b112108

__cxa_throw in section .text of C:\Users\Veter\Desktop\Dev\_src\robo_003\cmake-build-debug\robo_001.exe
```

Breakpoint is set successfully.

---

UPDATE1:
Simple project to reproduce the problem.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (untitled1 ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES})
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QObject>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow() {};
        ~MainWindow() override {};


    };
#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("robot");
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Figvam");

    MainWindow mainWin{};
    mainWin.show();

    throw std::exception();

    return QApplication::exec();

}
```

Without Qt5 all work well.

It seems the problem that "(gdb)info functions __cxa_throw" return twice __cxa_throw.

One from main binary, another from Qt5Core.dll.

```
(gdb) info functions __cxa_throw
All functions matching regular expression "__cxa_throw":
Non-debugging symbols:
0x00007ff76b112108 __cxa_throw
0x00007ffe67a75f68 __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
0x00007ffe67a75f70 __cxa_throw
```

But in old gdb it return only one __cxa_throw.

Comment: Try `break throw` to break whenever any exception is thrown.

Comment: "(gdb) break throw". I got: 
Function "throw" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]

Comment: Have you tried `catch throw`?

Comment: @Versum Sorry, I meant `catch throw`.

Comment: "catch throw" output: "Catchpoint 7 (throw)" But on throw program exited (not pause) with: 
[Thread 42504.0x7adc exited with code 3]
[Inferior 1 (process 42504) exited with code 03]". 
Anyway, I use Clion IDE and it use __cxa_throw for debugging. For normal CLion working it's need break __cxa_throw. Now I get "Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: Function __cxa_throw not defined" under CLion.

Comment: Re. `"But on throw program exited (not pause)..."`: are you certain the exit was due to an exception being thrown? Is it possible the exit was due to some other condition and no `throw` statement was ever reached?

Comment: @G.M. I certain.

Comment: I just tried it with a simple test program, and it works just fine for me with my gdb 12.1 build (both `catch throw` and `b __cxa_throw`). Do you have a small example that doesn't work?

Comment: @ssbssa Post is updated. There is a simple program to reproduce the problem on my pc.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with your Qt example. It's really weird.